# can't find connect to server (SMB) on fresh ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, smb

I can't find the connect to server dialog that had the SMB mount option?
was it removed? is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

It's sitting under Nautilus's File menu on my computer.